# Unable to send context to django template

Tags: javascript, python, django

Didn't find a solution to similar issue.
I have a list of tasks rendered on a page and after clicking on a title a modal window is popping up with a form to update the task. List and update are made in one class-based view. When a modal window is opened task id is received by views.py from AJAX to update my context in order to show saved data in form fields. I can see updated context with specific object when printing it in my views.py, but the object is not shown in HTML via template tag.
Please, help me to figure out what am I doing wrong.

Here is my views.py:

```
class KanbanBoardView(PermissionRequiredMixin, View):
    permission_required = ('projects.view_taskassign',)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = {
            'heading': "Kanban board",
            'pageview': "Tasks",
            'tasks': TaskAssign.objects.all(),
            'statuses': Status.objects.all(),
            'users': User.objects.all(),
        }
        if 'taskid' in request.GET:
            task_id = request.GET.get('taskid')
            task_object = TaskAssign.objects.get(id=task_id)
            context['task'] = task_object
            return render(request, 'tasks/kanbanboard.html', context)
        return render(request, 'tasks/kanbanboard.html', context)

    def post(self, request):
        if 'edittask' in request.POST:
            id = request.POST['id']
            deadline = request.POST['deadline']
            status = request.POST['status']
            user = request.POST['user']

            task = TaskAssign.objects.filter(id=id)
            task.update(deadline=deadline, status=status, user_id=int(user))
            return redirect('tasks-kanbanboard')
        else:
            status_id = int(request.POST.get('status'))
            task_id = int(request.POST.get('task_id'))
            task = get_object_or_404(TaskAssign, pk=task_id)
            task.status_id = status_id
            task.save()
            return JsonResponse({"message": "success"})
```

My JS script:

```
function editTask(event){
    let task_id = document.getElementById("uid");
    task_id.setAttribute("value", event);
       
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            'taskid': event
        },
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function (result) {
           console.log('Error!');
        }
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title mb-4">Planned</h4>
                <div id="task-2">
                    <div id="upcoming-task" class="pb-1 task-list">
                        <!-- task card -->
                        {% for task in tasks %} {% if task.status_id == 1 %}
                        <div class="card task-box" id="{{ task.id }}">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="float-end ms-2">
                                    <span class="badge rounded-pill badge-soft-secondary font-size-12" id="task-status">{{ task.status }}</span>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <p class="fw-bold mb-2">
                                        <a href="" class="text-dark" id="{{ task.id }}"
                                           data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop"
                                           onclick="editTask(this.id)">
                                            {{ task.title }}
                                        </a>
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="text-muted mb-2" style="line-height: 15px;">Description: {{ task.description }}</p>
                                    <p class="text-muted mb-2">Deadline: {{ task.deadline }}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {% endif %} {% endfor %}
                        <!-- end task card -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end col -->

    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title mb-4">WIP</h4>
                <div id="task-2">
                    <div id="inprogress-task" class="pb-1 task-list">
                        <!-- task card -->
                        {% for task in tasks %} {% if task.status_id == 2 %}
                        <div class="card task-box" id="{{ task.id }}">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="float-end ms-2">
                                    <span class="badge rounded-pill badge-soft-primary font-size-12" id="task-status">{{ task.status }}</span>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <p class="fw-bold mb-2">
                                        <a href="" class="text-dark" id="{{ task.id }}"
                                           data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop"
                                           onclick="editTask(this.id)">
                                            {{ task.title }}
                                        </a>
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="text-muted mb-2" style="line-height: 15px;">Description: {{ task.description }}</p>
                                    <p class="text-muted mb-2">Deadline: {{ task.deadline }}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {% endif %} {% endfor %}
                        <!-- end task card -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end col -->

    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title mb-4">Test</h4>
                <div id="task-2">
                    <div id="test-task" class="pb-1 task-list">
                        <!-- task card -->
                        {% for task in tasks %} {% if task.status_id == 3 %}
                        <div class="card task-box" id="{{ task.id }}">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="float-end ms-2">
                                    <span class="badge rounded-pill badge-soft-warning font-size-12" id="task-status">{{ task.status }}</span>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <p class="fw-bold mb-2">
                                        <a href="" class="text-dark" id="{{ task.id }}"
                                           data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop"
                                           onclick="editTask(this.id)">
                                            {{ task.title }}
                                        </a>
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="text-muted mb-2" style="line-height: 15px;">Description: {{ task.description }}</p>
                                    <p class="text-muted mb-2">Deadline: {{ task.deadline }}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {% endif %} {% endfor %}
                        <!-- end task card -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end col -->

    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title mb-4">Done</h4>
                <div id="task-3">
                    <div id="complete-task" class="pb-1 task-list">
                        <!-- task card -->
                        {% for task in tasks %} {% if task.status_id == 4 %}
                        <div class="card task-box" id="{{ task.id }}">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="float-end ms-2">
                                    <span class="badge rounded-pill badge-soft-success font-size-12" id="task-status">{{ task.status }}</span>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <p class="fw-bold mb-2">
                                        <a href="" class="text-dark" id="{{ task.id }}"
                                           data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop"
                                           onclick="editTask(this.id)">
                                            {{ task.title }}
                                        </a>
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="text-muted mb-2" style="line-height: 15px;">Description: {{ task.description }}</p>
                                    <p class="text-muted mb-2">Deadline: {{ task.deadline }}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {% endif %} {% endfor %}
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end col -->
</div>
<!-- end row -->


<!-- Modal window -->
<div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" id="uid">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="modal-content">

                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel" style="max-width: 25em">{{ task.title }}</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>

                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-lg-7">
                        <div class="modal-body" style="margin-left: 10px" id="task_modal_body1">
                            <input name="description" value="{{ task.description }}">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <label for="id_deadline"><b>Deadline:</b></label>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="datetime-local" name="deadline" id="id_deadline" value="{{ task.deadline }}">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-5">
                        <div class="modal-body">

                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="id_status" class="form-label"><b>Status</b></label>
                                <select id="id_status" class="form-select" name="status">
                                    {% for status in statuses %}
                                        <option value="{{ status.pk }}" {% if status == task.status %}selected{% endif %}>{{ status }}</option>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </select>
                            </div>

                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="id_user" class="form-label"><b>Assignee</b></label>
                                <select id="id_user" class="form-select" name="user">
                                    {% for user in users %}
                                        <option value="{{ user.pk }}" {% if user == task.user %}selected{% endif %}>{{ user }}</option>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </select>
                            </div>

                            <input type="submit" value="Edit" name="edittask" class="btn btn-primary">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you look at the developer tools in your browser, under the network tab, do you see the XHR listed you would be expecting?  If so, what does the response say for that request?

Comment: Add your template, and show the error, its unclear whats wrong

Comment: You are not sending the context object after updating. Hence form values are not updated. You can have the context object outside get method, so that it can be used by both post and get. If you post template code, we can work on this challenge effectively.

Comment: Added my template code

Comment: ja408, yes, I have XHR listed with the id and status code 200.

Comment: Walucas, I don't have any errors. The updated context is just not passing to the template.